# AI players stop attacking infected

Tags: left-4-dead-2

I just bought Left for dead 2 in the recent Steam sale and thought I'd try single player first. However trying to play the first campaign I always find my AI team mates stop defending themselves or attacking zombies at the start of the 2nd level. Which makes it seriously hard to keep them alive.

Has anyone else experienced this and know a solution?

Comment: hmm... I've never had this problem

Comment: You mean Dead Center Level 2? That is not normal. They should at least be giving cover and moving with you. Have you installed any mods or tweaked any settings?

Comment: Yep Dead Center Level 2. No mods, literally finished the download , installed and started playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, that's just how they are. Just ignore them as much as you can (impossible to ignore completely), and rescue them when necessary. 'least, that's how I usually treat it.

Comment: They are not firing their weapons at all and just standing there taking hits.

Comment: @Fishcake I know. It seems to be very hit or miss with regards to whether they help you or not. Sometimes for me, there's no problem and they help out often. Other times, I'd say they don't fire a shot the whole level. Sometimes they won't even help you up when you're down. If there is a "solution", I certainly didn't find it. Anymore, if I play, it's co-op with at least 1 close friend since the AI usefulness range is so very wide.

Answer (score 2):

Do this

1. On your Steam Library, right click on L4D2 and click on Properties
2. Go to the Local Files Tab, and then click on Verify Integrity of the Game files
3. Now you just wait for it and if something is wrong it should fix it and redownload the corrupted files.

Comment: +1; unable to replicate

Answer (score 1):

AI in Left 4 Dead 2 is not bad but pretty limited compared to an human. If you can, try playing with friends or other unknown player.

It is much more fun and no frustration due to strange bot behavior.

Comment: Yeah I'll go online I just wanted to get to grips with it first.

Answer (score 1):

The AI should shoot and defend along with you.  This just happened with the latest patch.  Do not believe they just hang out, or this is not normal.  I have been playing this game for as long as it have been out, and this just started happening.

Comment: The question is 3 years old. Not to say that one shouldn't try and answer an old question, just pointing out that this phenomenon is nothing new.

Answer (score 1):

The fix that worked for me is quitting the game and starting it again but sometimes these bots are a pain and I hate that they cause me to lose progress.